# Update Power Point slides from SQL data in real time

Tags: database, sql, powerpoint

I am wondering if there is any simple program available to allow me update slide show made in power point to control or update display slides while it is running, maybe using separate program with data from external data source?

We are try to do a large display screen for outside multilevel car park. We want a slide show with Power Point to use nice fades between screen slide for car price rates, advertisements and also how many spaces are there inside at the real time. The current space count is store in SQL database from the entry / exit gate.

I found some complex looking programs with google but want something simple and low cost if possible.

Thanks in advance,
Barry.

Comment: OP has not logged on since the day after posting this

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Intelli Power Point":

http://www.informationdisplaysystems.com

It displays the slideshow after replace the keywords in your powerpoint PPT file by your SQL query result, and keep update the PPT again in every loop of the slideshow with the updated SQL data.

Very easy to use, there is a built-in demo PPT and local SQL server with the software, you can just modify from that demo file.

Comment: Seems perfect and not too expensive at AUD 79. This ought to have been accepted as the answer, but the OP has not logged on since the day after posting this question. SAD. We need only the finest questioners